# Problem in loading images from URL in android

Tags: android, download, bitmap

I am making an application in android which loads Icon size images from URL

i have tried downloading images using the following code.

One image labeled default.png was downloaded from the given url but there was another image labeled v_1234.jpg is not being downloaded. I dont know whats the problem. it just returns me null for jpg image.

I am not sure that its a problem for .jpg format that my code is not downloading the jpg format images or Its the labeled name problem that due to Underscore (_) in the label makes it not downloadable..

Please help Friends you are professional in that field.

**CODE:**

```
URL url = new URL(detail.voucher_image.toString());
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.getImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: I faced similar issues randomly somtimes I get bitmap somtimes null so I shifted to store the image as a file and one file is downloaded then create a bitmap of it

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
InputStream reader;
reader=conn.getInputStream();
System.out.println("Compressed2!!!"+conn.getContentLength());
                int available = reader.available();

                int i=0;
                int count=0;
                int cc=0;

                while(reader.read()!=-1){
                    cc++;
                }
                System.out.println("available"+cc);
                data2 = new byte[cc];
                while ((i = reader.read(data2, count, data2.length-count)) != -1) {
                    count +=i;
                   cc++;
                }


                System.out.println("Compressed3!!!");
               // reader.read(data2,0,cc);
                System.out.println("Compressed!!!");
               // printBytes(data1,data2,"after");

                System.out.println("length b4!!!"+data2);


                System.out.println("data::"+new String(data2));
                System.out.println("The length is "+data2.length);
                bmp2=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data2, 0, data2.length);
                if(bmp2==null)
                    System.out.println("The bitmap value is null");
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp2);undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to get bitmap from url

```
public Bitmap imageConvert(String url){
URL aURL = null;
Bitmap bm = null;
try {
final String imageUrl =imgstr.replaceAll(" ","%20");
Log.e("Image Url",imageUrl);
aURL = new URL(imageUrl);
URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(is)); 
is.close(); 
} 
catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("ProPic Exception",e.getMessage());
}
return bm;
}
```